# Inner working of MySQL multivalue insert for InnoDB engine

Tags: mysql, innodb

Does MySQL do table-level lock when inserting a multi-value insert like below statement? This statement is atomic for InnoDB, so it will guarantee all or nothing. How does MySQL handle this underneath?

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )
```

I have read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html but cannot find anything particular to this related.

Comment: It does not lock the table and will only lock the inserted rows and inserted indexes.

Comment: @SoheilRahsaz thanks for responding. So lets say my column1 is the primary key then if it does row-level locking then in the multi-threaded environment how does it work ?

Answer (score 2):

InnoDB locks row not tables

---

Here I created a simple test case with 3 sessions using IntelliJ consoles with this sample data structure.

Engine: InnoDB (Note that I'm only talking about InnoDB here and I'm sure different engines are different)

Mysql version: 8.0.25

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `locktest`;
CREATE TABLE locktest
(
    id  INT UNIQUE KEY,
    val INT
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dataTest`;
CREATE TABLE `dataTest`
(
    id  INT UNIQUE KEY,
    val INT
);


INSERT INTO dataTest
VALUES (1, 1),
       (2, 2),
       (3, 3),
       (4, 4);
```

Now in session 1:

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE dataTest
SET val = 100
WHERE id = 2;
```

So now it's using row 2 and hasn't committed yet.

Then in Session 2:

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO locktest
SELECT id, val from dataTest
WHERE id in (1,2);
```

As expected, this doesn't succeed immediately because it's waiting for the lock on row 2 from `dataTest`. You can see here that it's waiting:

[image]

But it has succeeded in inserting the row with id 1 into `locktest`. How do we know this? Look at `Session 3`

Then in Session 3:

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO locktest VALUES (10, 200);

INSERT INTO locktest VALUES (1, 200);
```

[image]

Here it shows that inserting row with id 10 happens quickly but then it has to wait for the next insert into `locktest` because in session 2 we had inserted a row with id 1 and that session hasn't finished yet.

We conclude that MySQL doesn't lock table `locktest` completely and only locks the row with id 1 **(because id is unique)** and it lets row with id 10 be inserted.

Also, read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html) and sidenote, be careful about [Gap Locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks).